# Proof By ContraPositive: if xy is odd, then x is odd and y is odd

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

> If $xy$ is odd, then $x$ is odd and $y$ is odd

I was just wondering if the correct contrapositive would involve proving these three cases:

1) $x$ is even or $y$ is odd

2) $x$ is odd or $y$ is even

3) $x$ is even or $y$ is even

I'm not too sure about if the last case is necessary as in the answer to this question only the first two cases were shown. I guess what i'm trying to ask is why do we not check the last case, since it is a possible negation of $x$ is odd and $y$ is odd?

Comment: No, @user170039  It is the statement of the form $P \land Q$, where $P$ means x is odd, and $Q$ means $y$ is odd, the negation of which is $\lnot (P\land Q) \equiv (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$

Comment: @amWhy: Indeed. Nice catch. I have removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The counter-positive of the assertion

> if $xy$ is odd, then $x$ and $y$ are odd

is

> if $x$ is even or $y$ is even, then $xy$ is even.

And asserting that $x$ is even or $y$ is even is equivalent to asserting that we have one of the following possibilities:

1. $x$ is even and $y$ is odd;
2. $x$ is odd and $y$ is even;
3. both $x$ and $y$ are even.

Comment: though we need only two cases: 1. $x$ is even (and $y$ arbitrary); 2. $y$ is even (and $x$ arbitrary)